In IP XFRM, How is the Traffic flowing good when different encryption key(AES-GCM) being used on both end (DUT1 <---> DUT 2)?
I am using IP XRFM and noticed that the Traffic flowing good when different encryption key(AES-GCM) being used on both end (DUT1 <---> DUT 2). Generally the traffic shouldn't through, if diff encryption key used in both end rite. Any one faced this behavior? Please find the below configuration used.
DUT1 config
ifconfig eth5 80.80.80.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
ifconfig eth6:1 192.168.100.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
ip route add 40.40.40.0/24 via 80.80.80.2 dev eth5
ip route add 20.20.20.1/32 via 192.168.200.1 dev eth6:1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
arp -i eth5 -s 40.40.40.2 00:00:00:00:00:04
ip xfrm state add src 192.168.100.1 dst 192.168.200.1 proto esp spi 0x00000301 mode tunnel replay-window 0 flag af-unspec aead "rfc4106(gcm(aes))" 0x5588b8f82942ccbd627f0ea2c486ca370cd47a4a5588b8f82942ccbd627f0ea2c486ca37 128
ip xfrm state add src 192.168.200.1 dst 192.168.100.1 proto esp spi 0x00000302 mode tunnel replay-window 0 flag af-unspec aead "rfc4106(gcm(aes))" 0x7460aa9b1e2de4dcab4434650091adf000c85d4b7460aa9b1e2de4dcab4434650091adf0 128
ip xfrm policy add src 40.40.40.1/32 dst 20.20.20.1/32 dir out ptype main tmpl src 192.168.100.1 dst 192.168.200.1 proto esp mode tunnel
ip xfrm policy add src 20.20.20.1/32 dst 40.40.40.1/32 dir fwd ptype main tmpl src 192.168.200.1 dst 192.168.100.1 proto esp mode tunnel
ip xfrm policy add src 20.20.20.1/32 dst 40.40.40.1/32 dir in ptype main tmpl src 192.168.200.1 dst 192.168.100.1 proto esp mode tunnel
DUT2 config
ifconfig eth2 up
ifconfig eth3 up
ifconfig eth2 90.90.90.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
ifconfig eth3:1 192.168.200.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
ip route add 20.20.20.0/24 via 90.90.90.2 dev eth2
ip route add 40.40.40.1/32 via 192.168.100.1 dev eth3:1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
arp -i eth2 -s 20.20.20.2 00:00:00:00:00:05
ip xfrm state add src 192.168.100.1 dst 192.168.200.1 proto esp spi 0x00000301 mode tunnel replay-window 0 flag af-unspec aead "rfc4106(gcm(aes))" 0xe0eb173bc29323ba3b15e9563b5314d2dc848761e0eb173bc29323ba3b15e9563b5314d2 128
ip xfrm state add src 192.168.200.1 dst 192.168.100.1 proto esp spi 0x00000302 mode tunnel replay-window 0 flag af-unspec aead "rfc4106(gcm(aes))" 0x4b475c3f0a4dc863cb9cda809855cb3181949a5e4b475c3f0a4dc863cb9cda809855cb31 128
ip xfrm policy add src 20.20.20.1/32 dst 40.40.40.1/32 dir out ptype main tmpl src 192.168.200.1 dst 192.168.100.1 proto esp mode tunnel
ip xfrm policy add src 40.40.40.1/32 dst 20.20.20.1/32 dir fwd ptype main tmpl src 192.168.100.1 dst 192.168.200.1 proto esp mode tunnel
ip xfrm policy add src 40.40.40.1/32 dst 20.20.20.1/32 dir in ptype main tmpl src 192.168.100.1 dst 192.168.200.1 proto esp mode tunnel
